# How to insert period after qualifying capitalized letters?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How can I insert a period after any capitalized single letter that is not already followed by a capital letter according to the following rules:

1. It is the followed by a space; or
2. It is followed by another capitalized letter; or
3. It the last letter in the string and preceded by a space or capitalized letter

Sample Inputs/Outputs:

`Patrick TJ Stephens` becomes `Patrick T.J. Stephens`
`TJ Stephens` becomes `T.J. Stephens`
`TJ Stephens QC` becomes `T.J. Stephens Q.C.`
`Marissa C J Gilbert` becomes `Marissa C. J. Gilbert`
`Marissa C Gilbert` becomes `Marissa C. Gilbert`
`C Marissa Gilbert` becomes `C. Marissa Gilbert`
`Marissa Gilbert C` becomes `Marissa Gilbert C.`

I've been using:

```
$str = preg_replace( '/([A-Z])(?=\s|$)/', '\1.', $str );
```

Unfortunately, it turns `Patrick TJ Stephens` into `Patrick TJ. Stephens` instead of `Patrick T.J. Stephens`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translating all your requirements will need a lookahead and lookbehind as this regex:

```
$str = preg_replace('/(?<=[\hA-Z])[A-Z]$|[A-Z](?=[\hA-Z])/m', '$0.', $str);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HCNLyR/1)

Although this regex is more complex than [Casimir's simpler regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44467393/548225)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$str = preg_replace('/[A-Z](?![a-z.])\K/', '.', $str);
```

Not sure it follows your rules but it does the job.

or with this one: `[A-Z](?![^A-Z\s])\K`

Comment: That turns "Patrick TJ Stephens" into "Patrick T.J Stephens" with no period after the "J".

Answer (score 0):

And a version for dummies, by dummy me :)

```
  $str = preg_replace(
        array(
               '/([A-Z])(?=\s|$)/',
               '/([A-Z])([A-Z])/'
        ),
        array(
               '\1.',
               '\1.\2'
        ),
  $str );
```

Here's the [demo](https://repl.it/IewY/0)